# Access custom property in stencil html template

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I've created a new custom property for a product and I need to access it in the HTML template.

I can see that these are held under product.custom_fields, but how do you reference a key and value of a specific custom property?

For example, I have a custom field with key of 'note' and value of 'one'.

I've tried displaying 'note' and 'one' on the HTML template the following way:

```
{{ product.custom_fields.note[key] }}
```

I'm however getting 500 errors. I haven't found a reference that would explain how to do this.

Comment: The only way I found is using {{each product.custom_fields}} {{name}} {{value}} {{/each}} but this needs to iterate through each custom field all the time.

Comment: Are you talking about stencil template engine (named in the title) or handlebars template engine (named in the tag)?

Comment: In handlebars you simply write `product.custom_fields.note` to get the value, there is no way get the property name (but you know the name, aren't you?) - see example here: https://jsfiddle.net/veraee/2uv5hzmn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a much cleaner solution for accessing a custom field by name:

```
{{#filter custom_fields 'your-custom-property-name' property='name' }}
  {{value}}
{{else}}
  a fallback string in case you don't have it
{{/filter}}
```

This is an undocumented feature of the filter helper from [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers/blob/master/lib/array.js) repo. It allows you to filter on a specific property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}} 
  {{#if name '==' 'note'}}
    {{name}}: {{value}} 
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```